# VirtueMart Joomla product description

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I need to implement the following functionality:

I need to have multiple descriptions for each [VirtueMart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtueMart) product and display the descriptions individually based on what user clicks on. Consider the following example:

```
Link 1           Description 1
Link 2 Product 1 Description 2
Link 3           Description 3
```

- When user clicks on Link 1, I need to display Description 1 for
  Product 1;
- When user clicks on Link 2, I need to display Description 2 for
  Product 1;
- When user clicks on Link 3, I need to display Description 3 for
  Product 1.

I am assuming I can do it with conditional statements, but I am not sure how... How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) plugin

This will allow you to use php inside your content. The idea is to set some extra params to the url and then get them in a way like the following

```
<?php if(JRequest::getInt('part',0)==1):?>
description 1
<?php else:?>
description 2
<?php endif;?>
```

Do not forget to enable the content plugins from the VM configuration